# Convergence equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, grassmannian

If $G_k(\mathbb{R}^m)=\{ W: W$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m, \dim W=k \}$ and consider in $G_k(\mathbb{R}^m)$ one topology $\tau$ where $U\in \tau$ is open iff  the set $\widehat{U}=\lbrace v: v\in W\backslash \lbrace 0\rbrace, \mbox{for some}  \ W\in U \rbrace$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$

I'm testing the following:
If for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a basis $\lbrace u^k_1,\ldots,u^k_n\rbrace$ of $S_k$ such that $\Lambda=\lbrace \displaystyle{\lim_{ k \rightarrow +\infty}}u^k_1,\ldots,\displaystyle{\lim_{ k \rightarrow +\infty}}u^k_n\rbrace$ is a basis of $S$ then $\lbrace S_k\rbrace \subset G_n(\mathbb{R}^m)$ converges to $S\in G_n(\mathbb{R}^m)$.

My progress:

Let $U$ open of $S$ in $G_n(\mathbb{R}^m)$. Given that $\widehat{U}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\Lambda \subset \widehat{U}$, there $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $u^k_j \in \widehat{U}$ for all $k\geq k_0$ and all $1\leq j\leq n$. There $W_j\in U$ such that $u^k_j\in W_j$. But as showing $W_j=S_k$ for all  $1\leq j\leq n$?

Note: The other direction of the statement is also true but I only need the above.

This is an example of open

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\vecspan}{span}$The statement you wanted to prove is actually false, if I'm not mistaken. Here's a counterexample. Define $A \subset G_2(\mathbb R^3)$ by
$$
A = \left\{\vecspan\bigl\{(1,0,0),(0,1,t)\bigr\} : -1 < t < 1 \right\} \cup \left\{\vecspan\bigl\{(0,1,0),(1,0,t)\bigr\} : -1 < t < 1 \right\}.
$$
This is an open neighborhood of the element $S = \left\{ (x,y,z) : z = 0 \right\} \in A$ because
$\widehat A = \left\{ (x,y,z) : \lvert z \rvert < \max(\lvert x \rvert, \lvert y \rvert) \right\}$
is open.

Now define $\Lambda_k = \bigl( (1,0,1/k), (0,1,1/k) \bigr)$ and $S_k = \vecspan \Lambda_k$ for $k \in \mathbb Z_{>0}$. Note that $S = \vecspan(\lim_{k \to \infty} \Lambda_k)$.

However, we also have $S_k \notin A$ for all $k$ (a consequence being that $S_k$ does not converge to $S$). To see this, first note that $(1,0,1/k) \notin \vecspan \left\{ (1,0,0), (0,1,t) \right\}$ for $t \neq 0$; the reason for this is that when a point on that plane has nonzero $z$-coordinate, it must also have nonzero $y$-coordinate. Likewise, $(0,1,1/k) \notin \vecspan \left\{ (0,1,0), (1,0,t) \right\}$ for $t \neq 0$. And of course, neither $(1,0,1/k)$ nor $(0,1,1/k)$ lie on $S$. We have thus determined that each element of $A$ fails to contain at least one point of $S_k \supset \left\{ (1,0,1/k), (0,1,1/k) \right\}$. The desired conclusion follows.

---

**Appendix.** Judging by the critical response, some clarifications might be in order. While $k>2 \implies S_k \setminus \{0\} \subset \widehat A$, it nonetheless remains the case that $S_k \notin A$ for all $k \in \mathbb Z_{>0}$. The set $A$ is the union of the two families of planes specified at the top of the answer, nothing more, nothing less. In general, the implication $U \in A \implies U \setminus \{0\} \subset \widehat A$ is true, but the converse isn't.

There might also be confusion stemming from trying to use intuition from the canonical manifold topology on the Grassmannians. The $\tau$ topology from the question is strictly finer than the manifold topology. Thus open neighborhoods in $\tau$ do not necessarily contain every subspace that is sufficiently "close" in the usual manifold sense; while $(S_k)$ converges to $S$ in the manifold topology, the same sequence fails to converge in the $\tau$ topology.

Comment: What makes you think that $S_k$ is not in $A$ (for all $k$)?

Comment: $(1,0,1/k) \notin \vecspan \{ (1,0,0), (0,1,t) \}$ because on that plane, a nonzero $z$-coordinate implies a nonzero $y$-coordinate. Likewise, $(0,1,1/k) \notin \vecspan \{ (0,1,0), (1,0,t) \}$.

Comment: @studiosus So is there anything you're still unsure about in my answer? I'm open to improving the answer further and deleting if it's fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Your solution is correct now. +1.

Comment: @epimorphic Thanks for responding, I would inquire more please: How could modify the topology $\tau$ given for the sentence to be true?

Comment: @helmonio I actually saw your new question a few days earlier and have been thinking a bit about how I might respond. I'd agree with the suggestion of the 3rd comment on the new question that you should use the standard manifold/metric topology on $G_k(\mathbb R^n)$. The construction is more complicated than that for $\tau$, but the standard topology is more natural in the sense that open neighborhoods of $S\in G_k(\mathbb R^n)$ will contain every subspace which is obtainable by a sufficiently small rotation of $S$. (cont...)

Comment: @helmonio (...inued) You won't have $\times$-shaped open neighborhoods like my set $A$ and similar "bad" open neighborhoods that caused your desired convergence to fail in $\tau$.

Comment: @helmonio The 2nd comment over there seems promising as well, but I suspect the quotient topology will just be the manifold topology.

Comment: @epimorphic Again thank you

Comment: Correction/clarification to [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777749/convergence-equivalence/788599#comment1674399_788599): "The construction is more complicated than that for $\tau$" should read "The construction is more complicated than the one for $\tau$".

Comment: @Epimorphic I have dealt with this metric $d (X, Y) = \Vert P_X - P_Y \vert $, where $ P_x, P_Y $ is the orthogonal projector on $ X, Y $, respectively. But not get the desired assertion. would greatly appreciate if you could tell me if this metric or should I take another