# In search for a topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, grassmannian

I'm looking for a way to convergence on subspaces.

If $G_k(\mathbb{R}^m)=\{ W: W$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m, \dim W=k \}$ and consider in $G_k(\mathbb{R}^m)$ one topology $\tau$.

I would like to find a non-trivial topology for the following statement is true:

$\lbrace S_k\rbrace \subset G_n(\mathbb{R}^m)$ converges to $S\in G_n(\mathbb{R}^m)$ sss for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a basis $\lbrace u^k_1,\ldots,u^k_n\rbrace$ of $S_k$ such that $\lbrace \displaystyle{\lim_{ k \rightarrow +\infty}}u^k_1,\ldots,\displaystyle{\lim_{ k \rightarrow +\infty}}u^k_n\rbrace$ is a basis of $S$.

All suggestions are welcome!

Note:
I thought that the appropriate topology was $\tau$ where $U\in \tau$ is open iff  the set $\widehat{U}=\lbrace v: v\in W\backslash \lbrace 0\rbrace, \mbox{for some}  \ W\in U \rbrace$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$ but as shown in the following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777749/convergence-equivalence) is not true.

Comment: Since this is a generalization of the projective space, I would try to generalize that topology as well. (P.S.: I have no idea of where this may lead. I actually know nothing about Grassmannians)

Comment: Perhaps limit your basis to orthogonal bases (via Gram-Schmidt) then look at the Stiefel manifold and give the Grassmannian the quotient topology? In particular, let $V_n(\mathbb R^m)$ be the Stiefel manifold of orthogonal $n$-frames of $\mathbb R^m$, with projection map $p: V_n(\mathbb R^m) \to G_n(\mathbb R^m)$. Here it makes sense to talk about bases to a space. Topologize $V_n(\mathbb R^m)$ so that your limit gives convergence, then give $G_n(\mathbb R^m)$ the induced quotient topology.

Comment: It seems to me that the topology you mention is quite "unnatural" and I believe that using the standard topology inherited from $Gr\simeq O(n)/(O(k)\times O(n-k))$ would do. You may also have a look at "Plucker coordinates", e.g. [here](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.rice.edu%2F~evanmb%2Fmath465spring11%2Fmath465Grassmannians.pdf&ei=2PN2U8-tGMSb0QX8rIHwCQ&usg=AFQjCNGBbct-ba1QTWqWtEIvKCim3C5oIA&sig2=_bgVfyVDfAGD6rGgd1mZPQ&bvm=bv.66917471,d.d2k&cad=rja).

Comment: @PeterFranek Thanks for responding. I was testing this metric: $d(X,Y)=\Vert P_X−P_Y \Vert$, where $P_X,P_Y$ is the orthogonal projector on X,Y, respectively, But not verify the claim. You know another metric that can help?

Comment: What does “sss” mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topology induced by the metric $$d(X, Y) = \lVert P_X - P_Y \rVert$$ that you mentioned, where $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are respectively the orthogonal projections of $\mathbb R^m$ onto $X$ and $Y$, works.

(Note that this topology is in fact the standard topology mentioned by Peter Franek and others in the comments to the question. If you're curious about the equivalence of the various definition of this topology, you might start with [the section in the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian#The_Grassmannian_as_a_homogeneous_space) and [this question over at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/48440). But this is beside the point. All we need is that the map $X \mapsto P_X$ is an injection $G_n(\mathbb R^m) \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{m\times m}$, so that $G_n(\mathbb R^m)$ can inherit the metric topology on $\mathbb R^{m \times m}$ as an embedded subset.)

To see why, we use [this nice formula for the projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29#Formulas): If the columns of $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ form a basis of $X \in G_n(\mathbb R^m)$, then $$P_{X} = A(A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top.$$ Note that this is a *continuous* function of $A$. Hence, the convergence we have at the level of bases implies the convergence of the corresponding sequence of projections $P_{S_k}$ to $P_S$, and equivalently that of the sequence of spans $S_k$ to $S$.